# Play several videos using AVPlayer in a view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, avplayer

I have an `UIView` which contains some some texts and views. in each view I need to play a video with `AVPlayer` , but my problem is only the first view shows the video :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
func playVideo(name:String , onView:UIView) {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "mp4")
    let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = onView.frame
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    onView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()

}
```

Using the function :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//ScrollView
    scrollView.contentSize = menuView.frame.size
    scrollView.addSubview(menuView)

//Play videos 
 playVideo(name: "pizza", onView: videoView1)
 playVideo(name: "salad", onView: videoView2)
 playVideo(name: "fries", onView: videoView3)
}
```

when I run the app video only play in `videoView1` , any suggestion why this happens ?
 I also put my code in `viewWillAppear` , `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an alternative solution , I replaced `UIView` with `UIContainerView` and then link them with `Embed` to other view controller and play video in each view controller. Now it works perfectly as I expected.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to **Apple doc**:

**class AVPlayer**

> **Note**
>
> AVPlayer is intended for playing a single media asset at a time.